# Python reading X and Y values and assigning to Z specific X Y pairs

Tags: python, contour, fromfile

I have used python to create 2D XY plots in the past from pairs of data in a file, but now I need to create a contour plot from data I have in a file.  The file looks like this:

```
<Descriptive string>
<some "random" number>
<number of X values:nx>
<Number of Y values:ny>
X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
...
... Xnx
Y1 Y2 Y3 Y4 Y5
Y6 Y7 Y8 Y9 Y10
...
... Yny
Z(X1,Y1) Z(X1,Y2) Z(X1,Y3) Z(X1,Y4) Z(X1,Y5)
Z(X1,Y6) Z(X1,Y7) Z(X1,Y8) Z(X1,Y9) Z(X1,Y10)
...
... 
Z(X1,Yny) Z(X2,Y1) Z(X2,Y3) Z(X2,Y4) Z(X2,Y5)
...
...
Z(X2,Yny) ...
...
...
Z(Xnx,Yny)
```

So far I've been able to read the values of X and Y although probably not in the most convenient form, even the values of Z, but then I am unable to assign them properly so that Z1 goes with (X1,Y1), Z2 with (X1,Y2) up to Zny going with (X1,Yny) and at the end Znx*ny going with (Xnx,Yny).  Hope this is clear enough...  So far, this is the piece of code that I have:

```
import numpy as np

# Read from .dat file:
with open("trans_acrolein_ResWVFunAP1R12.dat", "r") as f:
    fl = f.readline()
    xnum = f.readlines()[2]
    ynum = f.readlines()[3]

# Initialize some variables to be lists.
xval = []
yval = []

# Read the values of the number of X and Y values.
for line in xnum:
    px = line.split()
    xval.append(int(px[0]))

for line in ynum:
    py = line.split()
    yval.append(int(py[0]))

linesx = np.ceil(xval/5.0)
linesy = np.ceil(yval/5.0)
linesz = np.ceil((xval*yval)/5.0)

with open("trans_acrolein_ResWVFunAP1R12.dat", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        x = []
        y = []
        for element in line[4:3+linesx].split():
            x.append(element)
            for element in line[4+linesx:3+linesx+linesy].split():
                y.append(element)
```

Since I don't know how to read all the elements consecutively I used first a way of counting the number of lines that have X values, then the ones with Y values, and finally the ones with Z values, but I guess its not very efficient.
I will really appreciate if someone can help me with this.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that `N_z_values = N_x_values * N_y_values`. If there are the same number of values on each line, then you should be able to parse all the data containing lines at once, then split it up according to `N_x_values`.

For example, if `N_x_values = 27` and `N_y_values = 28` and there are 5 values per line, then you could do

```
import numpy as np
data = []
N_x_values, N_y_values = 0, 0
with open(file_name, 'r') as in_file:
    # skip 2 lines, grab N_X, grab N_Y
    [in_file.next() for _ in range(2)]
    N_x_values = int(in_file.next().strip())
    N_y_values = int(in_file.next().strip())

    for line in in_file:
        line = line.strip().split(' ')
        data.append(map(float, line))

data = np.array(data)
data = data.reshape(np.prod(data.shape))
x_cutoff = N_x_values
y_cutoff = N_y_values
x = data[:x_cutoff]
y = data[x_cutoff:y_cutoff]
z = data[y_cutoff:].reshape(N_x_values, N_y_values)
```

Now your values are in arrays of the form

```
x.shape = (27, )
y.shape = (28, )
z.shape = (27, 28)
```

`matplotlib.pyplot.contour` can take these values directly. For example

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
f = plt.figure()
ax = f.add_suplot(111)
ax.contourf(x, y, z)
ax.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks.  This gives me an idea already.  But usually N_x_values is not equal to N_y_values, (the value of N_x_values appears on the third row alone, and the value of N_y_values on the fourth row alone, after that all the data starts in 5 columns). And values are indeed stored in 5 columns but N_x_values or N_y_values are not necessary a multiple of 5.  But there's always a change of line between values of X, Y and Z.  That's why I was using the linesx = np.ceil(xval/5) and so on, to determine the number of lines it has to read through for every variable.

Comment: Hey, I changed the code so that it should accept everything. You just need to parse `N_x_values` and `N_y_values` before hand. What the code does is parses all the data at once and stores it in an array of size `N_lines x 5`. Then it flattens this array and then segments pieces off for your `x`, `y`, and `z` arrays. It actually doesn't care what the length of the lines are or if each line has the same number of columns. As long as your know `N_x_values` and `N_y_values` a priori, it works fine.

Comment: I've been trying to run the script as you post it, and made also some changes, and I have been unsuccessful, even after reading documentation pages and so on... Sorry for asking again.  So, in my first line there is a descriptive string, in the second line there is a number (not iportant) the third line contains a number equal to the number of X values, fourth line contains a number equal to the number of Y values and from the fifth line on are the X values, then Y values, and finally Z values (number of Z values equals N_x_values*N_y_values).

Comment: Sorry, ran out of characters... one error I get in first place is that N_x_values and N_y_values can't iterate (that one happens just at the very beginning) if I comment that line were you set the value to 0, on the line N_x_values, N_y_values = ... I get "ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack"... and well on the many other versions I made I get other sets of errors that will make this post a lot bigger.  Sorry, and thanks for your help.

Comment: There was an error in the script. Notice above that lines 7-8 had changed. When I wrote it, I thought that N_x and N_y were on the same line, but I must have been confused with a different problem. I changed that. The fix should resolve the `ValueError` problem. An easy way to debug is: 1.) import `sys` at the top of the script. 2.) Make sure the script works in pieces. So starting from the top, make sure each chunk of code outputs what you think it should. For example, after lines 7-8, type `print N_x_values, N_y_values` then `sys.exit()`. The `sys.exit()` will stop the script at that point.

Comment: Once the `N_x/y_values` are correct, move on to the next piece of the code and see if it's collecting the code correctly. Keep moving through the script like that.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think I understand now the syntaxis of the way you skip lines. One thing, leaving the initializing values of N_x, N_y = 0 gives me the error "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable" removing that line solves the problem.  Using sys.exit is really helpful, something I will keep in mind from now on.  Now, with data.append(map(float, line)) I get "ValueError: could not convert string to float:" don't understand if it goes back to the beginning where is the only string in the whole file or why it gives that error. I will keep trying. Thank you very much again!

Comment: Ah, another error. That first line should be `N_x, N_y = 0, 0`. It's giving you an error because it's trying to broadcast a single int over two variables. I fixed it above. For the other error, try printing out what `line` looks like before we append it to `data`. It should look like `['number', 'number', 'number', 'number', 'number']`. If it doesn't, then we may need to adjust the `line.split()` above it. If the values in the data file are separated by commas or tabs, you could try `line.split(',')` or `line.split('\t')` respectively.

Comment: I thought about that before, but thought line.split(' ') can take care of "any" number of spaces.  The line printed looks like this `['number,'','number','','number','','number','','number']` I guess the main problem is that the way my file is printed, since positive numbers get three blank spaces in between and negative spaces get two blank spaces in between (because of the negative sign taking one space).  Also I thought .strip() was to ensure trailing or leading blanks was not a problem.  Thanks for your coments. @Bill

Comment: I used only `line = line.strip().split()` and that prints the lines correctly. That is without specifying a separator.

Comment: Well, now it goes to almost the bottom... but it gives me an error: "ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged" and that one is on the line `z = data[y_cutoff:].reshape(N_x_values, N_y_values)`.  Along with this I have a question when defining y as `y = data[x_cutoff:y_cutoff]` does that mean to take the value immediately after `x_cutoff` and "count" a number `y_cutoff` of values following the initial or how that interval is defined? thanks

Comment: I just printed what it has as x and it prints `N_x_value` number of lines not of elements (although they appear by line well separated as `['number', 'number', 'number', 'number', 'number']`, and same thing happens with y.  I think I must try to convert it into an array before? or something like that?

Comment: Comment 1: You are right. `data[x_cutoff: y_cutoff]` should be `data[x_cutoff: x_cutoff + y_cutoff]`, and you'd have to change it in the definition of `z` as well. Alternative, redefine `y_cutoff = N_x_values + N_y_values` and leave the rest as is.

Comment: To elaborate, data is an array whose length is `N_x + N_y + N_z`. Additionally, all the values in data are arranged such that `data = [x1, x2, ..., xn, y1, y2, ..., ym, z11, z12, ..., znm]`. What we want to do is slice the data array into x, y and z arrays. We do this by `x = data[0:n_x]`, `y = data[n_x:n_x + n_y]`, and `z = data[n_x + n_y]`. The `[n_x + n_y:]` means `[n_x + n_y: end of array]`.

Comment: After we slice up the three arrays, we want to reshape the z array so that it looks like a 2x2 matrix, where each row corresponds to each value in the x array and each column corresponds to each value in the y array. To do this, we say `.reshape(n_x, n_y)` which tells the array to rearrange itself into `n_x` rows and `n_y` columns. Sorry I wrote such sloppy code! I didn't have the data file so I never tested it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for following up this thread.  As soon as I get to my office tomorrow morning I will try this.

Comment: Once again I have another question.  As I mentioned before, now the problem is that apparently it recognizes as an individual element of the array `data` each line read, so `x` ends up being made of `N_x_values` of lines (each line having five elements), and not made up of numbers, but lines... each line still looks like `['number', 'number', 'number', 'number', 'number']` (so the splitting between numbers is well done, but then it takes each line as an element of the array. Thanks a lot for following. @Bill

Comment: Print out `data.shape` directly after `data = np.array(data)`. I expect it to be `(N_x/5 + N_y/5 + N_z/5, 5)`, but maybe I'm wrong. Also, in `x`, are the values being printed out `float`s or `str`s?

Comment: When I print `data.shape` it is `(N_x/5 + N_y/5 + N_z/5, )` so is not by 5 as you would expect.  the values are printed as floats.

Comment: Hmm, also print `data[0].dtype` and `data[-1].dtype`. It's possible that there is an empty list in there somewhere. If all the lines in `data` have length `5` then it should be a 2D array, not 1D. Try in your loop after the `line.split()` to do a `if len(line) < 5: continue`. See if that helps.

Comment: Ok.. If I add the line `if len(line) < 5: continue` it gets the array "properly" but, it skips those lines with only one element. The problem I guess is that although there are 5 columns, if N_x_values is not a multiple of 5, its last row will have less elements, the rest of the row is blank and in the next line starts the y elements (and same thing happens at the end of the y elements)... I thought that by using `strip()` that wouldn't be an issue...

Comment: Well, this could be circumvented in two ways. First, you could pad any row (presumably only the last of the x and y values) with zeros. This has some problems. Option 2 is instead of appending the whole line at once to `data`, you could set up another `for` loop to do `for el in map(float, line): data.append(el)` instead of `data.append(map(float, line))`. Then, we don't need `data = data.reshape(np.prod(data.shape))` either.

Comment: thank you so much, it finally worked, now I have to change some things on the plot to make it look as I want, but the data is been read as I wanted.  I really appreciate your time and help.  I've being using Igor to do my plots and analysis and recently (couple of weeks) I wanted to learn python, and with the 2D plots was doing ok, now that I had some data to work on for 3D plots wanted to try but was somehow different for the way my outputs present the data.  Thanks again very much.  Whenever I gain the 15 points of reputation, I'll come back to point the answer as useful Thanks again